# VirtualBox - Long Path in Shared Folder with OSX Host and Linux Guest

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have created a Linux (Ubuntu) VM by VirtualBox under OSX. But I'm experiencing `Protocol error` while creating files with long paths in shared folders (existed files are accessible though).

Is there any solution for this issue? I'm using VirtualBox 5.1.10. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you expand your question with an example of the error?  Can you reproduce the error reliably from the command line in a terminal?  Is the error the same from both the OS X host and the Ubuntu VirtualBox guest?

Comment: @StandardEyre Sure. For instance, I've shared a folder called `example`, so that I won't be able to `touch /media/sf_example/very/very/deep/path/example.txt` in the guest

Comment: Thank you for the reply to my comment.  Could you expand your question with an example of the question?  Please edit your question post to include an example of the command you run and an example of the  `Protocol error`   Thank you.